# Authentication and authorization not working for spring 4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring 4.0.0 version with spring security framework 3.2.3 added using maven.
Problem is that the pages which are supposed to be authenticated are not throwing any login form and rather showing the content.

web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.wiselife.in</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

WebMVCConfiguration (annotations based)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.wiselife.in")
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ AppSecurityConfig.class })
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    /*public @Bean TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    public @Bean TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer ret = new TilesConfigurer();
        ret.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" });
        return ret;
    }*/

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contactdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
        return new ContactDAOImpl(getDataSource());
    }
```

AppSecurityConfig: -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("tom").password("123456")
                .roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("123456")
                .roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("james").password("123456")
                .roles("SUPERADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("tom").password("123456").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("bill").password("123456").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("james").password("123456").roles("USER", "ADMIN", "SUPERADMIN");
    }

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/protected/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/confidential/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')").and().formLogin();

    }
```

Main Controller:-

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
        model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
        model.setViewName("home");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        model.addObject("contact", newContact);
        model.setViewName("ContactForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        contactDAO.delete(contactId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/protected**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView protectedPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security 3.2.3 Hello World");
        model.addObject("message",
                "This is protected page - Only for Administrators !");
        model.setViewName("protected");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/confidential**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView superAdminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security 3.2.3 Hello World");
        model.addObject("message",
                "This is confidential page - Need Super Admin Role !");
        model.setViewName("protected");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
        model.addObject("contact", contact);

        return model;
    }
```

Any help here will be really appreciable. 
AJ

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nasty pitfall with Spring's web security configuration: you must *either* annotate the class with `@EnableWebSecurity` *or* make it `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. When you have both, then the defaults from `@EnableWebSecurity` take precedence and your custom configuration is silently ignored. Therefore I expect your application to start behaving well when you remove the annotation.

Sice you don't seem to be using the per-controller-method security annotations, I would suggest also removing the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` annotation, which is used only to make that work. In that case you don't need the `configureGlobal` method. It may even be in collision with your `configure` method.

Comment: As suggested, i edited the AppSecurityConfig class and removed both annotations 
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)

also removed the configureGlobal function but now my application is giving me some error related to autowiring -

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exc...

Sorry for stupid questions but seriously new to spring.

Comment: The innermost nested exception explains what really failed.